# Setting up X server on Centos6 minimal

Tags: xorg, centos, x11

I'm trying to install Centos6, but as it turned out, DVD I downloaded was just couple Mb too large (CentOS-6.0-i386-bin-DVD.iso) for DVD to carry. So, to save time and don't download DVD again, I downloaded minimal (CentOS-6.0-x86_64-minimal.iso) and set up successfully.

At first, I did not get that anaconda stuff to show gui for install - only after 4th reinstall, it showed, so I thought install is OK, even thou, I did not get any possibility to customize installable packages. Ok, installed without delays. On first boot up, it did not show X server, just login prompt in a command line. Ok, I logged in, ran a `yum update` and `yum groupinstall "X Window System" "GNOME Desktop Environment"`, as *internets* suggested. Tried startx and it just flicker and popped out some errors `(EE) SIS(0): Illegal video RAM size (262144K) detected, using BIOS-provided info`, so I understood from *internets*, that SIS chipset is malfunctioning - something is wrong with integrated gpu - I put PCIe one inside. Reboot, `startx` and nothing - it flickered, popped some messages and then `Witing for X server to shutdown`, `ctrl+alt+F7` shows blinking caret, nothing more. Here is [Xorg.0.log](http://pastie.org/2985311).

Can anyone suggest step-by-step tutorial, **what needs to be done, to set up GUI on minimal Centos6 system AND make it default on startup**, so after boot, X server login screen appears, not the one in commandline.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From my webhost's knowledgebase:

```
If CentOS has already been installed without a graphical interface, 
you can install this with the following commands:

$ yum groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop" "Desktop Platform"

$ yum install gdm

If you would like this to be the default runlevel, you can edit 
/etc/inittab and set the default level to 5 instead of 3:

$ vi /etc/inittab

Change:
id:3:initdefault:

To:
id:5:initdefault:
```

Comment: This solved 4hrs of head ache. Thank you.

Comment: The above does not work for me with CentOS 7. X crashes immediately after installation: `error setting MTRR (base = 0xe000...`

Answer (score 0):

You can install this with the following commands:

1. cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
2. vi ifcfg-enp0
   press "i" insert
   //NOBOOT=yes
   press esc > :wq
   3.reboot
3. yum -y group install "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"
4. ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target/etc/systemd/system/defualt.target
5. reboot again!
6. yum groupinstall "General Purpose Desktop" -y or
   yum groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts" "Graphical Administration Tools" "Internet Browser" -y
7. yum groupinstall "Office Suite and Productivity" -y
8. yum groupinstall "Graphics Creation Tools" -y
9. yum groupinstall kde-desktop -y
10. startx or init 5